# How to add an additional bundle (config) to all Firebase fatal crashes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I would like to add a dictionary to all the firebase crash reports (fatal ones). Is this possible? If not, is there an alternative to send more information with crashes?

Comment: You have a logging API that you can use to put extra info in the crash logs.  That's it for now.

Comment: @DougStevenson I saw the logging API and I find it useful but, I wanted to send some state variables to debug some of the obscure bugs that we don't get in our dev environment. Are you guys planning to add such a feature in the future?

Comment: You can always send a feature request for the things you'd like to see (which we do take seriously), but I can't make any guarantee what will happen in the future.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/